# C# TabPage ImageKey not drawing

Tags: c#, image, tabpage

I have an Application that runs tests on a customers account in order to judge if their service is working correctly. During the process of running the tests, the application reads each test and checks to see if it passes / fails / etc... It plays a green checkmark  / red x on the tabPage itself as an imagekey... the imagekey is assigned as so

```
(tabPage as TabPage).ImageKey = "pass.png";
```

tabPage is actually an object that is passed through to the function so i can refer to it from a different method.

When the tabControl for the tabPage is created (dynamically), an imageList is added to the tabControl (which is where the images are pulled from).

```
(tabControl[0] as TabControl).ImageList = imageList2;
```

So when the method finally gets around to the code to assign the ImageKey it does run through the code, however it just shows up as a blank image. It's weird, because it works for some people and not others. It does not currently work on mine atm either and they do not show when I execute the source code. Does anyone have any ideas? Here's an image to help describe the issue... More code to follow if needed.
[image: Example Image]

Comment: If it works for some, make sure the bits per pixel for the image matches the desktop's. If the nature of image is such that it doesn't clearly show up due to BPP settings, then you might have to make sure that it does. You need to do some tricks for that.. have diff BPP images, convert the image to compatible format etc.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean on this, Can you try to clarify a little better?

Comment: Check the ImageList properly. Observe the TransparentColor field. It is useful when some color is supposed to be transparent. Then check whether the images you added for their `PixelFormat` values. Keep them same, if possible. Finally, check the `ColorDepth` of the image list. That, ideally, should match the pixel format of the images. In my opinion, 24 and 32 bit should be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your need for an answer has probably long-since passed, but I had the same problem, and here is my solution:

Setting the ImageKey does not work, but **setting the ImageIndex does cause the icon to display**. I made an enumerator that mapped the icons to their indices.

```
private enum TabIconCodes : int
{
    Stopped = 1,
    Running = 2,
}
unitTab.ImageIndex = (int)TabIconCodes.Stopped;
```

This is not an ideal solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 3):

Hy! Another solution on the same concept:

```
 tabp.ImageIndex = ImageListTabpages.Images.IndexOfKey("ImageKey")
```

It does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question was asked a long time ago but the answer provided here either is a workaround or not clear enough.

```
This does NOT show the image:
var tabPage = new TabPage("page text");
tabPage.Name = "pageName";
tabPage.ImageKey = "myImageKey";
TabPages.Add(tabPage);  //tab is added AFTER setting the ImageKey
```

```
This works fine:
var tabPage = new TabPage("page text");
TabPages.Add(tabPage);  //tab is added BEFORE setting the ImageKey
tabPage.Name = "pageName";
tabPage.ImageKey = "myImageKey";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before setting up the ImageKey for PageTab the TabControl of the PageTab needs to have ImageList set and PageTab has to be added to the TabControl